# Form within table contains dynamically created input parameters that are not being passed in IE 9 and 10

Tags: javascript, forms, dom, internet-explorer-9, parameter-passing

```
var i = 0;
var a = 3;
function addNewAnswer(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    if(i < 10)
    {   
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<font size="2" face="Courier New"><b>Enter Answer ' + String.fromCharCode(67+i) + ':</b></font>';

        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        var element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.size = 40;
        element1.type = "text";
        element1.name = "answer"+a;
        cell2.appendChild(element1);

        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        var element2 = document.createElement("input"); 

        element2.type = "radio";
        element2.name = "radios";
        element2.value = String.fromCharCode(67+i);
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
        i++;
        a++;
    }
}
```

My HTML Form:

```
<table>                                 
<tr>
    <form method=post  name="submitform" action="verify-qedit.jsp">
        <td>
            <form method=post  name="submitform" action="verify-qedit.jsp">
                <table id="dataTable">                      
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" align="left">Question</th>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>     
        </td>
    </form> 
</tr>                       
</table>
```

When I submit the form, I only can retrieve the parameters not created by the above javascript. It only works in compatibility mode - IE 8 standards and below. Please help because I have spent days trying to find out before posting this question.

Comment: What is i? in your condition: if (i < 10)

Comment: Agreed with previous comment that the `i` variable looks very suspect -- it could very easily be the cause of the problem, but we certainly can't be sure without knowing where it's being set and what it's being used for. I'd recommend not using a global in this way anyway -- you'd be far better off passing it into the function as a parameter, and then using `return` to pass it back out again if necessary.

Comment: off topic: I notice you're using a `<font>` tag in the code above. Please note that `<font>` is deprecated; it's use is not recommended in modern browsers. It is recommended to use CSS styles to specify the font instead.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, i is declared outside of the function, so an input field cannot be created once it is greater than 10 input text fields. So the problem is that when I submit the form using IE9 standards, the values are not passed, so request.getParameter("answer3") is null and so forth.

Comment: I guess I should have giving more context. The text fields are answers to a question. Two answers, a and b are required so they are not dynamic. However, if the user wants to create another answer, they have to click the button to add a text field to enter the text and a radio button to choose whether that answer is the correct one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344033/dynamically-added-form-elements-are-not-posted-in-ie-9

Comment: I finally got it to work. The javascript was not the problem. It was the location of my form which has not caused a problem except for IE9 when not in compatibility view. Thanks for your tips. I wouldn't have figured it out without all of your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with the javascript. It was because I was putting the form tag in the wrong place within the table after the tr tag instead of after the td tag.

```
<table>                                 
<tr>
    <td>
        <form method=post  name="submitform" action="verify-qedit.jsp">
            <table id="dataTable">                      
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="3" align="left">Question</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>     
    </td>
</tr>                       
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work on all the browsers you are targetting?

http://jsfiddle.net/4nbB5/1

```
function addNewAnswer(tableID) {
    var rowCount, row, cell1, cell2, cell3, element1, element2, char;
    var i = 0;
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    while (i < 10) {
        rowCount = table.rows.length;
        row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        char = String.fromCharCode(65 + i);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<font size="2" face="Courier New"><b>Enter Answer ' + char + ':</b></font>';

        cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        element1 = document.createElement("input");
        element1.size = 40;
        element1.type = "text";
        element1.name = "answer" + i;
        cell2.appendChild(element1);

        cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
        element2 = document.createElement("input");

        element2.type = "radio";
        element2.name = "radios";
        element2.value = char;
        cell3.appendChild(element2);
        i++;
    }
}
addNewAnswer('foo');
```

All I did was remove 'a', and declare 'i', change 'if' to while, changed 67 in fromCharCode to 65.. Looked to be what you may have wanted at some point so I stopped.

Comment: I tried this but I need i to be declare outside of the function and the while to be an if so when the function is called a new text field is created unless i >= 10. But using IE9, I still get null values for request.getParameter(answer3) and so on. The first two text fields are not dynamic because at least two answer fields are required.

Comment: Thanks for helping me. Once you cleaned up the javascript and confirmed that the function was okay, it allowed me to focus on what else could be causing the issue which was the location of the form.