# How to post dynamic fields in IE9

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a form in which users can fill static fields. Below them a button allows to add dynamically new fields :

```
<form action="url" method="POST">
  <table class="table" id="mytable">
       <thead>
           <tr>
               <th>Foo</th>
               <th>Bar</th>
           </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
       </tbody>
   </table>

  <button id="new-field">Add new fields</button>

</form>
```

Here is my JS code :

```
$('#new-field').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var i = $('#mytable tbody tr').length + 1;

        $('<tr><td><input type="text" name="newfield['+ i +'][foo]"></td><td><input type="text" name="newfield['+ i +'][bar]]"></tr>').appendTo($('#mytable tbody'));
});
```

New fields are displayed correctly, but when I post the form (via a submit button), new fields are not considered on IE9... It works on Firefox and Chrome.

Apparently here is a solution : [Dynamically added form elements are not POSTED in IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7344033/dynamically-added-form-elements-are-not-posted-in-ie-9)
But I can't use the compatibility mode for my project.

Have you got any solution please ?

Comment: perhaps you could copy the form fields to an object and submit it using ajax instead with $.post

Comment: You have a syntactical typo where you have typed `['foo']`

Comment: @cjross Indeed, syntax error when copying code thanks

Comment: @andrew Yes it could be a solution, with a redirect after submission. thks